# CSS not displaying on mobile devices on certain posts/pages

Tags: css, wordpress, ssl, https, mobile-safari

I’ve noticed that on certain posts/pages mobile devices running Safari or Chrome are not displaying the CSS and just the html and images. I thought this was due to Mixed Content being loaded over HTTPS, but I’ve updated the database and removed all full URL’s so that now they just start with “//” and no http/https, and confirmed that the affected posts no longer have any Mixed Content, and load with Green Secure https in the url.

Even with Mixed Content cleaned up, certain posts are still not displaying the post with the CSS. If I go into the post that is not loading correctly in the WordPress back end, and simply click the ‘Update’ button and nothing else, then refresh the post on the mobile device, it then loads the CSS and looks as it should.

I have over 1k posts, so either looking for help on why this is happening, or if there is a way to use SQL to “click” the Update button on every post. The affected posts seem to be totally random with no distinguishable pattern.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved using the Wordpress plugin 'Really Simple SSL'

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the path to your CSS content may have changed? Changing to https, or a different domain can affect this. Tapping the "update" button can refresh the paths.

You might try a plugin that will bulk update all your URLs, such as this:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Or if you prefer to run the SQL your self you could see this article:
http://vickyteinaki.com/blog/bulk-change-url-paths-using-sql/